# Problem in package manager occoured while adding APT for a third party software

Tags: package-management

I was trying to add a repository in **synaptic package manager** and I end up with an error.  This is what it shows when I open synaptic package manager.

```
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
Go to the repository dialog to correct the problem.
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.

W: Ignoring file 'Macaulay2.list.save.3' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
W: Ignoring file 'Macaulay2.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
W: Ignoring file 'Macaulay2.list.save.4' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
W: Ignoring file 'Macaulay2.list.save.2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

Actually,  I was trying to install a software called **Macaulay 2** following online instruction.

Answer (score 0):

It means that your repository files have an invalid extension. you should have extensions like `Macaulay2.list.save` or `Macaulay2.list` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

Rename these files in **Terminal** and then update repository:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/Macaulay2.list.save{.1,}  
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/Macaulay2.list.save.{2,3,4}
sudo apt update
```

Comment: Sorry sir, I am new on ubuntu. Can you please explain how to undo what I did? I mean how to remove these packages.@Ghasem Pahlavan

Comment: @ShahnawazAhmad please append output of this command to your Question to explain you how to remove this repository and add it again. `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Comment: This is what it shows                                                                                                                                                                                                 aims-ubuntu-sagemath-xenial.list
aims-ubuntu-sagemath-xenial.list.save
Macaulay2.list.save
ravefinity-project-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list
ravefinity-project-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save